# Why does this statically typed member access think it is a getter?

Tags: f#, duck-typing, structural-typing

[image: setter is a getter]

`rvm` is an object, not a function.

Why does the constraint `(^b:(member ReportSubTitle:(String -> unit)) rvm )` come up as a getter instead of a setter? Is this a Tooltip issue or something else?

Everywhere else where I've made use of statically typed generics, I find I don't even have to tell it the type at all. This doesn't work either:

```
// Setup the sub title with the total
let subTitleSetter = (^b:(member ReportSubTitle:_) rvm ) 
subTitleSetter ("Total: " + total.ToString("C") )
```

Moved this attempt into a function and tried what @kvb suggested

[image: no parens]

This is the only use whatsoever of `rvm` in the enclosing scope/method

Comment: Try without the parens around the member's type: `ReportSubTitle:String->unit`.  This differentiates a method from a function-valued property.

Comment: tried it, "Expected 2 expressions, got 1"

Comment: You have to supply both `rvm` and `test` as arguments at once (as a syntactic tuple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is the correct way for calling setters via static member constraints. I always find the feature a bit rough around the edges and prefer to use other options when possible (i.e. define an interface and access members via the interface).

That said, it looks like you can use `set_PropertyName` in the constraint. The following small example works fine for me:

```
type A() = 
  member val Foo = 0 with get, set

let a = A()
let setter v = (^b:(member set_Foo : int -> unit) (a, v) )

setter 42
a.Foo
```